# SpringBoot log4j2 is not logging in the file located in the /var/log/ folder

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

This is the config for my log4j2.properties file,

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = /var/log/some/sqs
#appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/sqs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
#loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.mybatchservice
logger.file.level = debug, info
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

In the above I changed the logger.file.name=com.mybatchservice to the root folder of my package. com.mysomeservice.sd.sqs.sqs
But its now throwing exception as follows :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 0
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.partitionOnCommonPrefixes(PropertiesUtil.java:555)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.build(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:481)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:323)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:695)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
    at com.mysomeservice.sd.sqs.sqs.MyApplication.<clinit>(MyApplication.java:26)
    ... 8 more
```

And on the 26 line I just have the lombok annotation
@Slf4j, as can be seen below java code snippet.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.DeleteMessageRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.Message;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    private static List<Message> messages = null;
    private static final Integer MAX_COUNT_OF_MESSAGES = 10;
    private static final Integer NUM_OF_THREADS_IN_POOL = 10;
```

Comment: What loggers are supposed to write to the `FileAppender`? Right now only the (probably non-existent) `"log4j2.properties"` logger writes there.

Comment: Sorry please elaborate more, this is the first time I am configuring the log4j2.properties, some real novice errors could be there. Please do throw some more light on that.

Comment: Do you want both appenders (the file and the console) to have the same content?

Comment: Yes, at least I should get to see them, then I may remove the console one. Please let me know where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: According to the line numbers in the stack trace, you have a property key `logger.<something_without_dots>`. Remove it.

Comment: Please kindly post this comment, as answer. I am thankful to you, also I shall for sure accept this as answer. But one more thing which line number in the stack trace mentions that the error is in log4j2.properties file having a property key "logger.<something_without_dots>". Please do elaborate on that in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see suggests that you have a property that:

- begins with `logger.`,
- does not contain any other dots.

(see [`PropertiesConfigurationBuilder#build()` line 174](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/3042e80fc6624e410925e4a264acddad92cc1541/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/properties/PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java#L174)).

A minor (easily reproducible) bug in Log4j 2.17.1 causes the configuration to fail. You can workaround the bug by removing the property (which is useless anyway).

**Edit:** I sent a small [PR](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/729) to fix the problem.